# Ubuntu unetbootin empty boot menu

Tags: 16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04 I made bootable windows 7 using unetbootin which I downloaded from the software centre to create a windows partation for games, but on restart the unetbootin menu doesn't have any options, its just blank. All there is is "default" and a countdown which resets after hiting zero. Is there an alternative software to make bootable USB using the win7 iso which is simple to download,install and use or a fix to the unetbootin problem.

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly found a solution, after trying tons of software here's what I did, installed Rufus on a friends laptop which had windows 10 and used it to make the iso work perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I use Multisystem. Run:

```
wget http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2
bunzip2 install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2
tar xf install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar
bash install-depot-multisystem.sh
```

to install it. Then open it and you will see this:

[image: Select USB Multisystem]

and select your USB. Then you will see this:

[image: Add distorts Multisystem]

Then just drag and drop the isos.

If this doesn't work, maybe use UUI in WINE. I haven't done this for ages, but give it a try.

Comment: I can't download Multisystem, I tried UUI and it isn't reading the win7 iso file.